# How to validate json schema using avj and postman

Tags: postman, ajv

I'm trying to validate the following json that looks like this:

```
{
    "errors": false,
}
```

using this on postman:

```
var Ajv = require('ajv'),
    ajv = new Ajv({logger: console, coerceTypes: false}),
    schema = {

        "errors": {
                "type": "number"
            }
    };


pm.test('Schema is valid', function() {
    var error = pm.response.json()['errors'];
    console.log("this is error: " +error);
    pm.expect(ajv.validate(schema, {errors: error})).to.be.true;
});

pm.test('Schema is valid different way', function() {
    var error = pm.response.json()['errors'];
    console.log("this is error: " +error);
    var validate = ajv.compile(schema);
    pm.expect(validate(pm.response.json())).to.be.true;
});
```

but it's always passing, even though my errors object is a `boolean` and not a `number`. What am I doing wrong?

note: the logs look like this

```
this is error: false
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check json schema using avj in Postman as follows:

```
    var Ajv = require('ajv'),
    ajv = new Ajv({logger: console}),
    schema = {
        "properties": {
            "errors": {
                "type": "boolean"
            }
        }
    };

pm.test('Schema is valid', function() {
    var error = pm.response.json()['errors'];
    pm.expect(ajv.validate(schema, {errors: error})).to.be.true;
});
```

---

Data:

```
{
    "errors": false
}
```

Result: Pass

---

Data:

```
{
    "errors": true
}
```

Result: Pass

---

Data:

```
{
    "errors": 123
}
```

Result: Fail

---

An alternate way

```
pm.test('Schema is valid', function() {
   pm.expect(typeof(pm.response.json().errors) === "boolean").to.be.true;
});
```

Comment: you are missing the point.. the data _is_ a boolean_ and i want to verify that it is boolean, and fail when it's a number

Comment: @abbood, Thanks, answer updated. Let me know still I'm missing anything!