# How to verify if a value is of format and/or type double using ajv schema validation?

Tags: javascript, postman, json-schema-validator, ajv

Im using Ajv version 07.

I am trying to validate that the value of a property, returned by the JSON response body is of type and format double in postman, using ajv validation, however, I'm not being able to do it. I've tried searching it online, but still did not find anything about it.

I've tried typing the following:

- "type" : "double",

  "format": "double"
- "type": "Double",

  "format": "Double"
- "type":"number"

  "format":"double"

All the above attempts were unsuccessful as they all come with an error message saying either:

- **Error: unknown type "double" is used in schema**

or

- **Error: unknown format "double" is used in schema**

Would anyone be able to help me with this please?

**schema**

```
var Ajv = require ('ajv'),
ajv = new Ajv ({logger:console}),
expectedResponseSchema = 
{
    "items": {
        "required": [
            "payments"
     ],
        "properties": {
    "payments": {
                "items": {
                    "required": [
                        "amount"
    ]
        "properties": {
                        "amount": {
                            "$id": "#/items/properties/payments/items/properties/amount",
                            "type": "number",
                            "format": "double"
                        }
   }
  }
 }
}
}
```

**Postman test**

```
var currentSchPmExpTest;

try{     
currentSchPmExpTest = ' expectedResponseSchema variable';
    pm.expect(ajv.validate(expectedResponseSchema, jsonData)).to.be.true;
pm.test('Test 1 - PASSED - expectedResponseSchema variable data matches schema returned by body response!', () => true);
} catch(e){
    pm.test('Test 1 - FAILED - Expected data does not match response body data!', () => {throw new Error(e.message + " in " + currentSchPmExpTest)});
}
```

**body response**

```
[
  {
    "payments": [
      {
        "amount": 2.200000045367898,

      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: What does your full schema look like in the app and what does your test script look like. This feel like it's half of the information.

Comment: @DannyDainton schema and postman test added.

Comment: @DannyDainton body response added.

Comment: Updated my answer to make your test a little easier to manage. I don't know if that is anything that will help with the value - you could try and use `pattern` and add some regex in there? I've seen `multipleOf` being used with `number` but I've not tried that.

Comment: Not sure, but is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/55021811?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you're getting the type and format from but as per the [AJV docs](https://ajv.js.org/keywords.html#type) (could be out of date) that isn't a valid `type`.

[image]

EDIT:

From your update, I would recommend changing the test script to something like this so that you correct part of the schema is getting checked:

```
let schema = {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
            "payments"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "payments": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "required": [
                        "amount"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "amount": {
                            "type": "number",
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

pm.test("Check Schema", () => {
    pm.response.to.have.jsonSchema(schema)
})
```

The `try/catch` block can be added around this if you need too.

Comment: Yeah, I came across that info as well. And then I did more research on it, to see if there was a way to instead check maybe for the **format** double, but without success.

Comment: It's not a valid type or format so that would always give you the same error though. What research were you doing, can you provide a link to where it said you can use double?

Comment: That is precisely what I have been trying to figure out, if it allows or not. But if it does not what is the alternative way to do this?

Comment: I don't know what you're validating against - There's nothing in the question that tells people what the value in the response is going to be. Can you update with an example response body please.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. However, this still does answer my question: Is it or is it not possible to check that a value is a double?

Comment: Your question centers around a piece of made up functionality that you have tried and it's failed, with an appropriate error.  I don't know if there is anything that will help with the value - you could try and use `pattern` and add some regex in there? I've seen `multipleOf` being used with `number` but I've not tried that. Ultimately, if its not part of the JSON Schema standard, it's not going to work.